# How does Alternating Bit Protocol work?

Tags: network-protocols

From Wikipedia entry on ABP ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_bit_protocol ):

> When A sends a message, it resends it continuously, with the same
>   sequence number, until it receives an acknowledgment from B that
>   contains the same sequence number. When that happens, A complements
>   (flips) the sequence number and starts transmitting the next message.
>
> When B receives a message that is not corrupted and has sequence
>   number 0, it starts sending ACK0 and keeps doing so until it receives
>   a valid message with number 1. Then it starts sending ACK1, etc.

I do not understand the particulars.

I understand the pretext and the whole thing with acknowledgements, but the process itself is described differently in different publications.

My question can be summed up with the following two:

1. What does it mean "...and keeps doing so"? Does it mean that the receiver can send two consecutive acks down the ack channel without any activity from the sender at all? I.e. at that point it is not synchronized with the sender at all?
2. What does it mean "resends continuously"? Same as above - is sender completely independent of the receiver during this resending?

There is an alternative coverage of the way it works here, but it gives a conflicting picture again: http://staff.science.uva.nl/~psf/specifications/abp.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "synchronized with the sender". The protocol is pretty simple though, you keep re-sending a message over and over until you receive an ACK for it. The one sending the ACK keeps re-sending that ACK until it receives a new message (where new means it has a different sequence number compared to the last message it received).

Comment: I guess synchronized with sender would mean that the channel is full duplex - the receiver can send as many asks as it wants, while the sender may or may not keep resending the same message.

Comment: You need to send messages/acks in both directions, in that sense, it's full duplex. The receiver sends acks for a particular message until it receives a new message, not "as many as it wants". That means, as long as the protocol is operational, it will send acks. forever and ever. The sender, once the protocol is operational (i.e. the first message is sent, and no one has shut the thing off) , the message will be repeatedly sent until the sender gets an ack for that message, it doesn't chose to send the message just once, or 10 times. It re-sends that message until it receives an ack.

Comment: Moreover, the acks are not acke'd, that is, the sender does not inform the receiver that "I got your ack, now stop sending more acks". So acks will be sent forever.

Answer (score 7):

First this is a full duplex line as both sides send data continuously.
This protocol is very similar to [Stop-and-wait ARQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop-and-wait_ARQ).
In Stop-and-Wait:

```
Side A:

 1. set index=0
 2. Send DATA(index) ,set timeout and waits for ACK 0 or timeout
  - If timeout back to 1
 3. If received ACK(index) set index^=1
 4. goto 2

Side B:

 1. Set index to 0
 2. If received DATA(index) Send ACK(index) and index^=1 //(xor)<br>
    else send ACK(index^1) 
 3. goto 2
```

In ABP is also one data packet at a time, the difference is that instead of passively waiting for ACK you keep sending the same data until the first ACK is received.
this protocol has a faster error recovery but is very poor in terms of power efficiency

For your questions:

1. Receiver is syncronized with the sender.

   > **When B receives a message that is not corrupted and has sequence
   >   number 0, it starts sending ACK0 and keeps doing so** until it receives
   >   a valid message with number 1

   keep doing so for every packet it receives with sequence 0.
2. Sender is partialy independent of the receiver in the sence that it keeps sending the same data over and over again, but not entirely as it will move to the next sequence when it receives the ACK.